# Creating a VPN without a router for gaming

Tags: 14.04, vpn, lan, port-forwarding

I am trying to Create my own VPN for gaming purpose. I keep coming across port forwarding in forums. I use ubuntu 14.04 lts and have a wimax connection which is basically consists of a LAN cable to my pc and I do not use a router. Is it possible to set up a VPN without a router? I did try hamachi but was experiencing problems which is why I have decided to try and set up my own VPN.

Comment: Not true @Neil.  There are plenty of users who connect their computer directly to their modem.  These users have no router on their end.

Comment: Some routers run Linux. You're running Linux.... of course it's possible. ;-) But where are you trying to connect to? A friend's network?

Answer (score 3):

**PPTP VPN**

**Run this command to install the needed packages:**

```
sudo apt-get install ppp pptpd
```

**Configure the ip range:**

```
sudo nano /etc/pptpd.conf
```

Add these lines:

```
localip 10.89.64.1
remoteip 10.89.64.100-150
```

Server is set up to use IP `10.89.64.1` and distributing the IP range `10.89.64.100` to `10.89.64.150` to PPTP clients.
Change these as you wish as long as they are private IP addresses and do not conflict with IP addresses already used by your server.

**Configure DNS - this is what clients use for a DNS server.**

Edit `/etc/ppp/pptpd-options`:

```
sudo nano /etc/ppp/pptpd-options
```

Add or edit these lines:

```
ms-dns 8.8.8.8
ms-dns 8.8.4.4
```

**Create a PPTP User.**

Edit `/etc/ppp/chap-secrets`:

```
sudo nano /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
```

Append a line at the bottom so that your file looks something like:

```
# client    server  secret          IP addresses
test        pptpd   abcd1234        *
```

**Configure NAT - you have to do this, if you want clients to have internet connection.**

Edit `/etc/rc.local`:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Add the following to the bottom right before “exit 0” line:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

**Enable IPv4 forwading:**

Edit `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Uncomment the following line:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Run this command to reload changes:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

Reboot the server.

**Client side configuration:**

**Linux**

[image]

**Windows**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do this, but perhaps one of the most documented ways is to use OpenVPN: https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/openvpn.html

Also read this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: k let me go through thsese.. thnx in advance